# How to populate dropdown items from JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a select element and I want to add select options from javascript. I have a ajax method and this method returns JSON object like;

```
"{"serverTypes":["WINDOWS","LINUX"]}"
```

I want to add options from this JSON. Is there any way to do this?

```
<select id="serverTypes" name="serverType" class="form-control"></select>
```

**EDIT:**
Setting value is not working

```
$('#serverTypes').val(jsonData);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can loop through the `JSON` and [**append()**](http://api.jquery.com/append/) the values:

```js
var json = {
  "serverTypes": ["WINDOWS", "LINUX"]
};
for (var x = 0; x < json.serverTypes.length; x++ ) {
  var option = json.serverTypes[x];
  $('#serverTypes').append('<option value="' + option + '">' + option + '</option>')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="serverTypes" name="serverType" class="form-control"></select>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var data = {"serverTypes":["WINDOWS","LINUX"]};
var serverTypes = data.serverTypes;

var option;
for (var i in serverTypes) {
    if (serverTypes.hasOwnProperty(i) && i!="length"){
        option = $('<option></option>');
        option.val(serverTypes[i]);
        option.text(serverTypes[i]);

        $("#serverTypes").append(option);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="serverTypes" name="serverType" class="form-control"></select>
```

Comment: Just the worse way I've ever seen to loop through an array!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Have you seen better implementation in pure JS, working also on IE<=8?

Comment: What about `for(var i = 0; i < serverTypes.length; i++) { ... }`??? Are you familiar with it???

Comment: It's much better. Anyway, there is no need for rage here, so calm down please.

Comment: There is no rage! I just gave you a hint that's all!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir so you meant to say for each is a worse way to go through the loop? Care to elaborate why?

Comment: I didn't say `forEach` is a worse way, `forEach` will be great for this!